# Magento - Registration error - 1054 Unknown column 'ca.sort_order' in 'order clause'

Tags: mysql, magento, mysql-error-1054

I'm receiving this error when I attempt to create a new account on my Magento store.

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'ca.sort_order' in 'order clause'
/home/user/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
/home/user/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
/home/user/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
/home/user/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(333): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
/home/user/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(734): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
/home/user/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(783): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
/home/user/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(696): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->_fetchAll(Object(Varien_Db_Select))
/home/user/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(617): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->getData()
/home/user/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php(729): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->load()
/home/user/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Form.php(222): Varien_Data_Collection->getIterator()
/home/user/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Form.php(320): Mage_Customer_Model_Form->getAttributes()
/home/user/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php(262): Mage_Customer_Model_Form->extractData(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
/home/user/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Customer_AccountController->createPostAction()
/home/user/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(253): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('createpost')
/home/user/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
/home/user/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(340): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
/home/user/public_html/app/Mage.php(627): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
/home/user/public_html/index.php(80): Mage::run('', 'store')
{main}
```

Some background info: I'm using a template that was built for 1.4.x but I'm currently using version 1.5.0.1 stable.

I attempted the SQL fixes found here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/214185/#top but it did not work. Any ideas?

EDIT: Website can be found at http://allyourga.me

EDIT 2: *Errors removed because they are unrelated*

Comment: Can you confirm the theme is to blame? Quickly switch to the default theme that comes with 1.5.0.1 and see if the error still occurs.

Comment: I'm having trouble resetting to the default theme. I've set the package to Default and all the other options to 'modern' or 'blank', but nothing changes despite refreshing/deleting cache. My custom theme is located in base/theme100, so I don't see why it's behaving this way.

Comment: Category, product and CMS pages can override the chosen theme but (AFAIK) the customer pages must follow what is set in admin under _System > Configuration > Design_. Try stepping through the stores in the configuration scope (that's the drop-down in the top left corner of _Configuration_) and see what theme each is using.

Comment: By convention custom themes shouldn't really be in the "base/*" folder. I would have it as "theme100/default" instead.

Comment: Each store config is using the same as the Default Configuration. Also, the design options are greyed out when I'm not editing Default Configuration. Please see the original question for updated logs...maybe they will give you a better idea of what's going on.

Comment: I completely agree regarding the theme conventions. This was a theme I purchased and that's how it was organized for some stupid reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I had a seriously defective database. I suspect the problem might have arisen either when uploading sample data from a purchased Magento template or when I was migrating my website from one server to a new one.

I fixed it by running Magento's database repair tool which can be found at the following link: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/db-repair-tool

The errors that popped up were a lot of `Added missing foreign key(s)` and two `Added missing fields`. For a full report on the errors that popped up, go to the following Stack Overflow question:

[Magento - Database repair tool - Added missing foreign keys problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5761298/magento-database-repair-tool-added-missing-foreign-keys-problems)